# Some php and html codes generated also in csv file

Tags: php, html, csv

I'm having a minor problem when generating **`.CSV file`** in `PHP MySQL`. When I generate **`.csv`** from my page it also **`import the HTML codes.`**

I'm having two files for this report generation process,

- **`reports.php`** - where the **`HTML`** can be found here and also the `query` for search data that will be generate.
- **`generate-csv.php`** - where the process for import `csv` can be found here.

If I input **`exit();`** after the php codes in the `reports.php`, it will display blank page only.

The sample structure display of `generated csv` was like this:
[image]

Here is my code:
**reports.php**

```
  <?php
   session_start();
   include_once "dbconnect.php";
   date_default_timezone_set('Hongkong');

   //Validate Login
   $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
   $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
   if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
            {
                header("Location: index.php");      
            }//end of Validation Login

    //Setting up Variables for Search form
    if (isset($_POST['generate'])) {

    $month = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['month']));
    $year = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']));
    $status = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']));


    if (empty($month) && empty($year) && empty($status)) {
          echo '<script>alert(\'Select atleast 1 filter\')</script>'; 
          exit;        
         }

    //condition of search
         //Single Search
         if (!empty($month)) {
         $sql = "SELECT `subscribers`.`cus_id`, CONCAT (`subscribers`.`fName`,' ',`subscribers`.`lName`),`transactions`.`month`,
         `transactions`.`year`, `transactions`.`subscriptionStart`,`transactions`.`subscriptionEnd`,`transactions`.`subsStatus` 
          FROM `subscribers` 
          INNER JOIN `transactions`
          ON `subscribers`.`cus_id` = `transactions`.`cus_id` 
          WHERE 
          `transactions`.`month` = '".$month."'
          ORDER BY `cus_id` ASC ";

         } if (!empty($year)) {
          $sql = "SELECT `subscribers`.`cus_id`, CONCAT (`subscribers`.`fName`,' ',`subscribers`.`lName`),`transactions`.`month`,
         `transactions`.`year`, `transactions`.`subscriptionStart`,`transactions`.`subscriptionEnd`,`transactions`.`subsStatus` 
          FROM `subscribers` 
          INNER JOIN `transactions`
          ON `subscribers`.`cus_id` = `transactions`.`cus_id` 
          WHERE 
          `transactions`.`year` = '".$year."'
          ORDER BY `cus_id` ASC ";

         } if (!empty($status)) {               
        $sql = "SELECT `subscribers`.`cus_id`, CONCAT (`subscribers`.`fName`,' ',`subscribers`.`lName`),`transactions`.`month`,
         `transactions`.`year`, `transactions`.`subscriptionStart`,`transactions`.`subscriptionEnd`,`transactions`.`subsStatus` 
          FROM `subscribers` 
          INNER JOIN `transactions`
          ON `subscribers`.`cus_id` = `transactions`.`cus_id` 
          WHERE 
          `transactions`.`subsStatus` = '".$status."'
          ORDER BY `cus_id` ASC ";

         //Compound Search

         } if (!empty($month) && !empty($year)) {
           $sql = "SELECT `subscribers`.`cus_id`, CONCAT (`subscribers`.`fName`,' ',`subscribers`.`lName`),`transactions`.`month`,
         `transactions`.`year`, `transactions`.`subscriptionStart`,`transactions`.`subscriptionEnd`,`transactions`.`subsStatus` 
          FROM `subscribers` 
          INNER JOIN `transactions`
          ON `subscribers`.`cus_id` = `transactions`.`cus_id` 
          WHERE 
          `transactions`.`month` = '".$month."'  
          AND `transactions`.`year` = '".$year."'
          ORDER BY `cus_id` ASC ";

         } if (!empty($month) && !empty($status)) {
           $sql = "SELECT `subscribers`.`cus_id`, CONCAT (`subscribers`.`fName`,' ',`subscribers`.`lName`),`transactions`.`month`,
         `transactions`.`year`, `transactions`.`subscriptionStart`,`transactions`.`subscriptionEnd`,`transactions`.`subsStatus` 
          FROM `subscribers` 
          INNER JOIN `transactions`
          ON `subscribers`.`cus_id` = `transactions`.`cus_id` 
          WHERE 
          `transactions`.`month` = '".$month."'  
          AND `transactions`.`subsStatus` = '".$status."'
          ORDER BY `cus_id` ASC ";


      } // More SQL Here I just delete it for short code explanation...



      $_SESSION['sql_query'] = $sql; // I stored this data to use in generate-csv.php file

  if ($result=mysql_query($sql))  {
       $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

             if($query_num_rows == 0){ 
          echo "<script> alert('No Records Found!')</script>"; 
      } else { 
          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
            echo "";

        }// end of while 
    }//end of else 

    }
    }

    ?>

<!-- This is the HTML codes Generated -->
<html>
<body>
    <form action="generate-csv.php" method="POST">
    <label>Month</label>
        <select name="month">
        <option>JANUARY</option>
        <option>FEBRUARY</option>
        <option>MARCH</option>
        <option>OCTOBER</option>
    </select>
    <label>Year</label>
        <select name="year">
        <option>2015</option>
        <option>2014</option>
    </select>
    <label>Status</label>
        <select name="status">
        <option>FRESH</option>
        <option>RENEWAL</option>
        <option>WINBACK</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="generate"  value="GENERATE">
    </form>
</body>
```

**generate-csv.php**

```
            <?php
        include_once "dbconnect.php";
        include_once "reports.php";

    echo mysql_error();
       //$sql will came from report.php 

        if($result = mysql_query($_SESSION['sql_query'])){
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {   
            echo "<script> alert('No Records Found!')</script>";  
            $columns_total = mysql_num_fields($result);   


        // Get The Field Name
        for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
        $heading = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
        $output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
        }
        $output .="\n";                    
        }  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {

                        for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
        $output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
        }
        $output .="\n";
        }
        $filename = date('Y-m-d-h:iA');
        $x = ".csv";
        header('Content-type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.''.$x);
        echo $output;
        header('report.php');


        exit;
        }?>
```

**Thank you.**

Comment: Always use `die;` or `exit;` after redirecting a user (`header("Location: index.php"); die;`). If you do not then the script will just continue executing.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: Thank you.

Comment: but if I use this before the `HTML` codes , the `HTML` not displaying.

Comment: @RensTillmann, output was in the generate-csv.php, I will put it wait.

Comment: @RensTillmann : `generate-csv.php` codes added.

Comment: Put exit or die before header(); function in generate-csv.php

Comment: Also wonder what is inside report.php?

Comment: Please  put `$output = '';` after including reports.php

Comment: @RensTillmann: Typo error there but it was same codes in reports.php hehe. but by the way, if add exit or die before header(); it will not generate the .csv file due to it can't search the query.

Comment: @RensTillmann: Thanks no more $output error.

Comment: I also think you should seperate the login check, and remove the include of reports and replace it with the login check. That will automatically fix your issue, cause no html will be generated.

Comment: @RensTillmann: Hmm, I will try that but I think that is not possible due to I stored SESSION `sql_query` in `reports.php` and used it in `generate-csv.php`

Comment: No it is ok, because it will only destroy if user is not logged in. It shouldn't matter.

Comment: Other way would be to wrap the html in a check: `if (isset($_POST['generate'])) {` maybe try that first, its easier i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reports.php put html in if statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['generate'])) {
    ?>
    <!-- This is the HTML codes Generated -->
    <html>
        <body>
            <form action="generate-csv.php" method="POST">
                [...]
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Or make seperate login verification file and replace `reports.php` for it inside `generate-csv.php`

Comment: blank page sir, but I guess it's okay for now I just simple remove the the codes when generated, I accept your answer because of `$output` it was so annoying. Thanks!

Comment: Ok good, i am sure you will figure out why you getting a blank page :)

Answer (score -1):

You are not supposed to write any HTML in `reports.php` file as it becomes a part of exported `csv`. Instead, you should only write PHP code that will retrieve results from database and display in the `csv`.